# Span tag doesn't work in text-image or text combinations

Tags: html

I have a piece of code and it seems that my code doesn't care about my span tag, I don't know if it is the problem of my browser (Chromium Edge) or my code, all my websites seems to have this problem. **ALSO THIS ONLY HAPPENS IN TEXT-IMAGE COMBINATION OR JUST TEXT, NOT IN IMAGES. THE SNIPPET WILL HELP YOU UNDERSTAND BETTER.** That means whenever I want to show an image exactly like this:
text   But what my span does is:
text

I hope that gave a better understanding

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span>
            <p>This is text</p>
        </span>
        <span>
            <p>It doesn't work with spans.</p>
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603381616642-42b585a184b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="Image #1">
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603132852827-5857c966512e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="Image #2">
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span>
            <p>This is a image text combination</p>
        </span>
        <span>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599993771158-370837d1dba8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
                alt="ImageText">
        </span>
    </body>

    </html>
```

The image might appear to be in div state because of the size of the post area. Expand to get accurate results.

Comment: What do you mean by "my code doesn't care about my span tag"? Is it just because your image appears larger than the span tag?

Comment: Why do you place block elements such as ```p``` inside an inline element such ```span```? Why not put them inside a ```div```?

Comment: I wanna make them appear side by side one contains the value and other contains normal text lik: NAME: SAMUEL

Comment: So you wanna display the name left side and the image right side (side by side). Is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `display: inline-block` to make a set of components inline. Here's a simple example. Since the image you're using is somewhat big, it is displayed on a separate line in your browser. You can fix this by defining a `width` and/ or `height` to the image.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p style="display:inline-block">This is text</p>
        <p style="display:inline-block">It doesn't work with spans.</p>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603381616642-42b585a184b0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Image #1" style="display:inline-block; width:100px">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603132852827-5857c966512e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="Image #2" style="display:inline-block; width:100px">
    </body>

    </html>
```

I'm still not clear what you're trying to achieve with spans here. If you want to surround a particular `<p>` tag with a `<image>` tag, I would recommend you to use `<div>`s instead of spans.